# What is the best way to use user environment in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have Jenkins set up on MacOS and want to execute commands that are installed on my user (e.g. Ruby, cucumber). Unfortunately, Jenkins does not use Environment vars of current user, so all installed programs does not work correctly (such as Ruby, and its dependencies).
For example, for Ruby and Cucumber I have to manually specify all necessary envs vars, including the `$PATH`

Is there a correct way to use current user environment without manual ENV set up or EnvInject plugin or the `environment {}` block in jenkinsfile?

I want that all vars user environment and system environment variables would be accessible in Jenkins job without manual updating of environment every time I install new package